# Filter has_many by attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find the best solution to filter the objects in a has_many association. What I have for a setup is

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Then in my CompaniesController#show method what I'd like to do is filter the products by it's title.

```
def show
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  # Then I just want the @company.products where title = params[:title]
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The 'Filterrific' rails gem is a great tool to do exactly this. The documentation has a page about building ActiveRecord scopes to filter by attributes of a has_many association: http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/active_record_scope_patterns.html#filter_by_existence_has_many

Answer (score 0):

Where is your controller action getting the product title (params[:title]) from?  If you're just passing it in as a search term submitted through a form, then you should be able to run something like....

```
 @products = @company.products.where("title = ?", params[:title])
```

EDIT: 
Storing the associated products in the @company variable would be problematic because then @company will contain an array of associated products (instead of a Company object), which not only limits the information you can access about the specific company in your show action from that variable, it also becomes confusing (e.g you're using a variable named @company to store a list of *products* associated to a company)

Comment: This is the show method method in my CompanyController though. I just want to return the @company instance.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't create a separate instance variable to store the associated products? So what you're saying is you want to store the associated (filtered) products in @company?

Comment: Exactly, if that's possible but I suppose doing it that way will also accomplish what I want.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I think that approach could cause some problems for you however. I edited my earlier answer with why I think so.